# UITableViewCell with left and right labels. How to make them display correctly?

Tags: ios, swift

I have an UITableViewCell with 2 labels which can have different content. Sometimes the left label is very big and the right label is small, or empty or sometimes the right label contains a lot of information.

Is it possible to make them display correctly (i.e. no label should be truncated and the hight of the labels should be as small as possible) only by playing with the constraints and content hugging/compression resistance priorities?

I already tried adding constraints for minimum width, or changing the priorities for compression and hugging to 1000, but I always have some issues like either the text is truncated (see screenshot) or one of the labels is displayed on 10 lines and the other on only one line (see the second screenshot).

Here is some sample data that I'm playing with (demo project available here https://github.com/adi2004/iosamples/tree/master/TableView):

```
    let data = [
    (left: "left one two three four five", right: "7"),
    (left: "left one two three four five 6 7 more here", right: "right one two three four five 6 7"),
    (left: "left one two three four five 6 7", right: "right one two three four five 6 7 something"),
    (left: "6 = ", right: "right one two three four five 6 7"),
    (left: "left one two three four five 6 7 right one two three four five 6 7 eight right one two three four five 6 7 eight", right: "")
]
```

Here are some samples of the issues I'm facing: 
[image: Imgur]

-- or --

[image: Imgur]

Comment: Hello You can achieved this using Content Hugging Priority ! Please Check my Video it's solved Your Tableview UILabel issue Hope it helpful for you
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g7Hlf7U0A9w

Comment: Thanks, Yogesh. But this still doesn't solve the problem when you don't know in advance which label should be bigger, or you reach the case where one of the labels gets squished and it will take too much vertical space.

Comment: did you try using `UIStackView`?

Comment: Please check once’s if you don’t know which label but using this priority you can done this And please tell me in which case you stuck now

Answer (score 7):

First of all check this screenshot. Is it fulfilling what you want?

[image]

From your comments on other questions, i can say, this one is what you were looking for.

These are steps that i have taken for creating the cell for this:

1. Add `TableViewCell` in your tableview, give identifier and cell class to it.
2. Add `UIStackview` in this cell with `Alignment` = `Fill`, `Distribution` = `Fill Proportionally`, `Spacing` = 0 . Give top, bottom, leading, trailing constraint to stackview, currently I used value = 12.(use whatever marging you want)
3. Add 2 UIViews inside this stackview, add background to both view, rightnow, i gave green and red to each one.
4. Now add UILabel to each UIView, set `numberOfLines` = 0, give top, bottom, leading and trailing constraints with value 0 to each label. Now, just connect the IBOutlets to respective cell class.

Your required cell is ready, set value you want in datasource and run the code. Let me know any further help you required. Make sure you are adding UILabel inside UIView, not directly to UIStackview. This is done because, multiline label inside stackview will never give you proper result.

**UPDATE:**

As @Gal pointd out that above code is not working while dequing.. Here, is changes that i made to resolve the same.

**Change 1 :**
Updated `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to invalidate `intrinsicContentSize` of containerViews and asking cell to layout the constraints again. Here, is my implementation:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TestCell") as! TestCell;
    cell.leftLabel.text = data[indexPath.row].left;
    cell.rightLabel.text = data[indexPath.row].right;
    cell.leftLabel.superview!.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize();
    cell.rightLabel.superview!.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize();
    cell.layoutIfNeeded()
    return cell;
}
```

**Change 2:**
Making above single change were working for all the cases, except that one in which any label's text value was empty(in that uiview was apparently removed out from stackview, by stackview itself). So, to prevent this, i have again updated my above `cellForRowAtIndexPath` code, making sure that any label's text is not getting empty. If empty, then adding just empty space there. It will be like this,

```
let leftText = data[indexPath.row].left;
if leftText.isEmpty{
    cell.leftLabel.text = " "
}else{
    cell.leftLabel.text = leftText;
}

let rightText = data[indexPath.row].right;
if rightText.isEmpty{
    cell.rightLabel.text = " "
}else{
    cell.rightLabel.text = rightText
}
```

After making above change. The screenshot will have very minor small slice, if you hide the background, then you cant find that, it exists there. Here, is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer Mehul! It looks great in your screenshot. I also tried it in my sample project, and it works, but... sadly or mysteriously when I scroll through the table, the cells that are dequeued, are not showing properly. See here: https://imgur.com/a/L0LuDnx

Comment: It seems to be getting better. I think, in the end, there is some code required to make this work properly.  I tried your changes and with the data source sample that I posted and it works fine! But if I only add these 2 new values: `(left: "left label only, the other one is empty string", right: " "),
        (left: " ", right: "right label only, the other one is empty string")`, I see that some cells are still not dequeued properly: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pvGFRjFuOkU

Comment: @Adi :  I think you have not applied my updated code changes, I have checked by adding above lines as you suggested. It is working 100% fine.

Comment: @Adi : Here, you can see the video of the same: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/7b78a335065d10a3ae801adcb993ecb020190102052317/74a43ec23bf5aa3bbfd5aeb03256686320190102052317/5b65f8

Comment: Thanks @Mehul Thakkar in your video it looks good, but I also applied the code changes from your answer and still I'm facing problems. You can check out the code on github. Can you maybe share your code?

Comment: @Adi Here is code: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/0b23be89ba54245a4cffee7a624f8fdc20190102110425/7f71473c3bce1bac78df6eea7a5aefdf20190102110425/57a3a3

Comment: @Adi : Let me know.. if you are unable to get anything from the code

Comment: Hi @Mehul Thakkar. Using your project, and my datasource I get the same issues. I updated the number of sections to 10 and the `data` constant. See here: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/72ff0f38f418d30f80c7abfbce12d40420190102130654/62f11c16499bcc50a1c11569526bc5a020190102130654/3c222e

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186067/discussion-between-adi-and-mehul-thakkar).

Comment: Hii @Adi, actually i were busy with some work from last 2-3 days. Now, let me know, what problem you are still getting?

Comment: Using your project, I still can reproduce the problem, if I just modify the datasource.

Comment: @Adi: What have you changed? Let me give details, i might possibly suggest some right way. I have tried all types of data.. short/long etc for the same and all worked perfectly fine.

Comment: Could you download the code that I send you? I mentioned my changes in the comment from `Jan 1 at 18:02`

Comment: I'm testing with the latest Xcode, on an iPhone 8 simulator, and it always reproduces.

Answer (score 2):

Main idea is to declare how wide should labels be. To do this, you have to declare some rules.

Start with deciding, which label will have bigger priority, so let's say you need bigger priority for left label, so set its **Horizontal Content Hugging Priority** bigger than of right label

[image]

Now for both labels set their minimal width. This you can achive by setting width constraint with certain constant and relation **Greater Than or Equal**

[image]

---

[image]
[image]

if you need to have always same "spacing" between labels, set their common constraint with relation **Equal**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tip Robert. I think this might be close to what I need, but even if I add the widths constraints, sometimes the cells are not displayed properly when they are dequeued. See here: https://imgur.com/a/1Ncg1pc . I also added a demo project to GitHub: https://github.com/adi2004/iosamples/tree/master/TableView

Comment: @Adi do you want same spacing between cells? Set their common constraint with relation *Equal*.

Comment: @Adi second problem (label with no text) is causes because of width constraint, label will always have minimal width equal to width constraint. If you want to avoid it, you can hide label where there isn't any text.

Comment: The spacing isn't important. I'm interested only in showing the content of the labels with a decent UI. The second label can also have something really small, like `1`.

Comment: @Adi Look, in this case you have to give rules how these labels should be wide. Xcode/Swift won't do this for you

Comment: what kind of rules?

Answer (score 2):

One more approach with `UIStackView`,

[image: Image 1][image: Image 2][image: Image 3]

**Notes:**

- `UITableView` should have,

  ```
  tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
  tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
  ```
- Keep `Label 1` and `Label 2` `numberOfLines = 0`
- `UIStackView` should have `Fill Proportionally` distribution

Comment: I have tried with `UIStackView` as well, but if I use `Fill Proportionally` and label 2 is empty and Label 1 will not use all the horizontal space.

Comment: BTW, using `UIStackView` with `Fill Proportionally` only works if `numberOfLines = 1`